# Android C2DM Accounts

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have an Android application that uses the C2DM service. I also have a server that integrates with C2DM. And I succeeded in registering from Android and from the server to the C2DM servers.

The problem is that I can send a message only to the account that is  signed in to the C2DM service (in the website and allow this service). This account is my server account also.

How can I send C2DM messages to other Gmail Accounts?  Can I get C2DM messages in Gmail accounts on Android?

Comment: You can only send C2DM messages to accounts that have registered to receive them from your app. It's not clear from your question that you have registered the accounts that you are failing to send messages to.  Have you?  Documentation: [Registering for C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#registering)

Comment: I have registered the accounts that I failing to send messages to